# ReactDOM to render multiple elements using the same class at ones?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-dom

I have a multiple elements using the same class and having the same content.

So I can I use ReactDOM to render them at ones instead of:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Footer source="./data/nav.json"/>,
    document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[0] //mountNode
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Footer source="./data/nav.json"/>,
    document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[1] //mountNode
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Footer source="./data/nav.json"/>,
    document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[2] //mountNode
);
```

It would be best if I can do it dynamically as I wouldn't know how many these multiple same elements are.

Is it possible?

**EDIT:**

```
var elementLength = document.getElementsByClassName("footer").length;
if (elementLength > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < elementLength; i++) {
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Footer source="./data/nav.json"/>,
            document.getElementsByClassName('footer')[i] //mountNode
        );
    }
}
```

it will call `./data/nav.json` multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

Something like (not tested):

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.getElementsByClassName('footer'),
  function(el) {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Footer source="./data/nav.json"/>,
      el
    )
  }
)
```

edit: now tested

Comment: thanks for the update. but this is going to loop `<Footer source="./data/nav.json"/>` multiple times. so it is calling `./data/nav.json` times. can i just call it once but render it to the multiple elements?

Comment: sorry it seems that it just calls that `./data/nav.json` once. i just re-checked...

Comment: actually it calls `./data/nav.json` multiple times for the first load. then just call it once afterwards unless u refresh the page.