# Is it possible to use a React component from within an HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

What I want to do is have a video with a set of controls below it. There are many places where I will need these controls, so I have decided to use React to render them so they are easily reusable.

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './styles.css';

class VideoControls extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>TESTING</div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <VideoControls />,
  document.getElementById('controls')
);
```

```css
/* code for tags */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background-color: rgb(48, 48, 48);
}

body {
  padding: 16px;
  /* overrides default w3.css */
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif !important;
}

video {
  display: block;
}

/* specialised code for other elements */
.video-panel, .video-panel-second {
  background-color: rgb(75, 75, 75);
  color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
  height: 45%;
  width: calc(50% - 11px);
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.video-panel-second {
  margin-left: 16px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="w3.css"/>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.min.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  <title>Editor UI Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="video-panel w3-container w3-padding-24 w3-round">
    <video id="source-video" src="/css-vse/assets/PostingLetter.MOV" height="100%" width="100%">Video not displayed.</video>
    <div id="controls"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="video-panel-second w3-container w3-padding-24 w3-round">
    <video id="timeline-video" src="/css-vse/assets/Walking.MOV" height="100%" width="100%">Video not displayed.</video>
    <div id="controls"></div>  
  </div>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to render a `<VideoControls>` within `div#controls` but I keep getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Identifier" when trying to do so. Is it possible to use the `<VideoControls>` React component from within my HTML file, or do I have to make the entire page a React app?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: are you using babel? i see you use jsx in the script but i do not see you explaning how you are linking your react code with the html page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using id to render the Component, use a class. Get the elements with the class name and in a loop render your react component.

[Follow this answer I found on StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40022574/reactdom-to-render-multiple-elements-using-the-same-class-at-ones), will help you sort this out.

Working Example.

```
<!-- Index.html -->
<div id="app">
  INSIDE APP DIV
  <div class="here">

  </div>
  <div class="here">

  </div>
</div>
```

And the React Component

```
class VideoControls extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return (
        <div>My VideoControls</div>
    )
    }
}

// getting all the divs with class here
let myContainerLength = document.getElementsByClassName("here").length;
if (myContainerLength > 0) {
    // if there are more than one instances of element with the class `here`
  // loop through the elements with class `here` using and index `i`
    for (let i=0; i<myContainerLength; i++) {
    ReactDOM.render(<VideoControls />, document.getElementsByClassName("here")[i]);
  }
}
```

Working example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/)

Comment: I still get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" and the component does not render.

Comment: @HoWingYip Give this one a go. It works as expected.